# Difference between "Looks OK" and "Other Action" after up or down vote in First Answers review queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, first-answers

There are currently four actions in the First answers review queue:

> Looks OK
> This answer is good as-is and not low quality (be sure to vote
> accordingly).
>
> Edit
> Improve and correct problems with this answer yourself.
>
> Share feedback
> Leave a helpful comment for the new poster.
>
> Other action
> You have flagged the post or taken other actions, and have finished your review.

The fourth one "Other action" is only available after a flag is raised, or a vote is cast.
Why is this option available after an upvote is cast and what is the difference, if any, between choosing "Looks OK" or "Other action" after I already casted an upvote?

Comment: A question can be worth an upvote to you while not being OK. For example, if it's a problem that you yourself have and you want an answer to, you might upvote it, but the question could still require editing, or might not be totally up to snuff, in which case, it doesn't look OK.

Comment: Even if you consider the question to be good enough for an upvote, there could be some edit necessary.

Comment: You specifically go to an upvote in your question because that is probably what you did to trigger this question, but I would imagine that the option also appears when you cast a downvote, right? That would be the more logical path for me to choose "other action". You downvoted (or flagged), can't edit yourself to improve, don't want to leave a comment. -> Other action.

Comment: "Other action" is also available after leaving a comment on the post.

Comment: @dan1stisonstrike so, after upvoting, either it needs an edit or some other type of feedback or looks OK. IMHO, "Other action" should be available only after flagging.

Comment: @Chenmunka I didn't notice that. That is also redundant (we already have "Share feedback"). Just take the other action away and replace it with "Flag the post" (not really). I actually don't like that and think "Other action" is a better word compared to "Flag the post" as it would not encourage flagging, hence not increasing erroneous flag count. As I said, "Other action" should be available after flagging and downvoting.

Comment: There's another option that gets its own button: **Skip**.

Comment: I'm actually wondering what "other action" actually does. aka, does the post get removed from the review queue, or is it treated the same as the "skip" option, or something else entirely?

Comment: Technically I think after three "Looks OK" votes, the question is taken out of the review queue. "Other" probably doesn't do that, even if you upvoted.

Comment: @jps I've encountered obviously off-topic questions (e.g. library recommendations) that actually helped me, though. It's a little confusing in that case whether I should upvote it for helping me or if I should downvote/VTC for being off-topic.

Comment: @jps There are plenty of cases where something is both useful and a duplicate, though, so in that case it makes sense to both upvote and vote to close. It doesn't look ok in the sense that it's a duplicate, but if it's well-formulated and uses different search terms than the duplicate, it's still helpful.